# Jquery how to append and remove on a div click event

Tags: jquery, html, click, append

I am new to using jquery and would like to know how to append and also remove the IDs from divs using the click event and appending to html. In the code below I have been able to append the IDs from clicking on a div, but am not sure how to remove. Whichever divs are highlighted yellow should be the ones that are appended. Clicking again on the div to remove the highlight should also remove the ID from the html. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.click').click(function() {
    var bg = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: bg == 'yellow' || bg == 'rgb(255, 204, 204)' ? 'transparent' : 'yellow'});
  });
});
$(function( ){
    $('#div1').bind('click', click);
    $('#div2').bind('click', click);
    $('#div3').bind('click', click);
});
function click(event){
    $('#p1').append(event.target.id + ",");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="click" id="div1">click me</div>
<div class="click" id="div2">click me</div>
<div class="click" id="div3">click me</div>
<p id="p1"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little cleaner to use a CSS class instead of changing the styling directly. That way you can take advantage of the handy `toggleClass` function to turn the highlighting on and off. It's also easy to test if a div is highlighted: `div.is(".highlighted")` or `div.hasClass("highlighted")` will tell ya.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.click').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    // Can use one CSS selector to find all three divs and bind them all at once.
    $('#div1, #div2, #div3').bind('click', click);
  });

  function click() {
    var p1 = $("#p1");

    if ($(this).is(".highlighted")) {
      p1.append(this.id + ",");
    }
    else {
      p1.text(p1.text().replace(this.id + ",", ""));
    }
  }

</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .highlighted {
    background: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to Keep other functions in separate block from one handling **ready** event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var divs = new Object();

    function click(event){
        var did=event.target.id;

        if($("#"+did).css('backgroundColor') == 'yellow')
            divs[did]=true;
        else
            divs[did]=false;

        AppendText();
    }
    function AppendText(){
       var txt="";
        for(var x in divs)
            if(divs[x]==true)
              txt +=x+",";

        $('#p1').html(txt);
    }      
</script>
```

Now hookup clicks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('div.click').click(function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: 
                bg == 'yellow' || bg == 'rgb(255, 204, 204)' ? 
              'transparent' : 'yellow'});
      });
        $('#div1').bind('click', divclick);
        $('#div2').bind('click', divclick);
        $('#div3').bind('click', divclick);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your example clicking on the div to remove the highlight doesn't remove the ID from the html but it does prevent another ID from being appended. Can you show how to remove as well?